# switching branches and how to reset database using EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a `__MigrationHistory` table and a migrations folder in my visual studio data project.  I need to switch to a different branch in git to investigate a defect so I need to reset the database but then switch back and continue with my work.

Is this possible? I'm concerned if I try and work out how to reset my database to investigate the defect (i.e. delete my migrations from the `__MigrationHistory` table and delete the migrations files) I'll loose my work when I need to switch back to my branch?

What is the solution around this problem?

**Update after deleting my entries in the migrationhistory table**

I get the following results when trying to run database-update?  Do I need to delete the corresponding migration files as well?

```
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
```

**Second update**

After backing up the database and truncating the migrationhistory table I get the following error

```
There is already an object named 'Customer' in the database.
```

Answer (score 2):

To revert the database to a previous version use this command in the package manager:

`Update-Database -TargetMigration "NameOfPreviousMigration"`

Entity Framework runs the `Down` migrations on your database and keeps the `_MigrationHistory` in sync for you. There should be no need to manually delete records.

You will need to revert your code too because Entity Framework will throw errors or attempt to update the database (depending on whether you have automatic migrations enabled) if the model and the database don't match.

When you are done, run `Update-Database` without the `-TargetMigration` command switch to run the `Up` migrations again

Reference:

http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/12/entity-framework-migrations-tips/